A British drama movie from 2003-2013 with a cab driver
I'm looking for a British drama movie. The theme was several people's daily life in a poor neighborhood in London. I guess it was a South London, because people and the apartments were in a really bad condition. 
The theme was like New York I love you (2008), Valentine's day (2010), Scenes of a Sexual Nautra (2006), etc.. with the stories of different people, but the genre was drama not comedy or romance.  
There was a 50-55 year old fat (above 120 kg, 260 lbs ) taxi driver, driving classic black cab. He was chatting with his fares during the way. One of this trips the fare was an old lady and she asked as if his son is fat like him, and he replied yes. The trip was very long. I think to France or Netherlands. His about 20 years old son was also fat like him and the kids of neighborhood were trying to piss of him. One of these incident, he wanted to catch the kids but he had an heart attack and fell down.
There was a young woman who had a jackass boyfriend. He was beating him when he's mad and demanding money from her. Her mother told her to break up with him, that she deserves better man, but she didn't listen her mother mostly. Finally she given up and broke up with him. She was so poor and did prostitution for money. She had long black hair, black eyes, white skin, about 1.65 m - 5' 5'' height, normal weight. Her boyfriend was white, tall, 1.88 m - 6' 2'' height, short black haired, had a beard and muscled . 
It was a low budget and probably low rated movie. Highly possible that the IMDb rating is below 5. I hope you guys find out.

Now that's a detailed question. ;) +1 & posted a match

You're looking for Mike Leigh's All Or Nothing from 2002.

Penny's love for her partner, taxi-driver Phil, has run dry. He is a gentle, philosophical guy, and she works on the checkout at a supermarket. Their daughter Rachel cleans in a home for elderly people, and their son Rory is unemployed and aggressive. The joy has gone out of Phil's and Penny's life, but when an unexpected tragedy occurs, they are brought together to rediscover their love. All or Nothing is set on a London working-class housing estate over a long weekend, and also tells the stories of a range of Phil and Penny's neighbors, some of whom become involved in the family's lives, and all of whom experience an emotional journey

The cab driver is the great Timothy Spall and his son is James Corden. Everything you said is there (his passenger asking him if his son is fat, his son having a heart attack etc.) Here's the trailer:


 

Yess .. this is it . Surprised about the imdb rating : 7,6 !! Thank you man .

@abacak No problem! (And yes, Leigh films are usually highly rated.)

@abacak You seem to have various different unregistered accounts. In order to use the site to its fullest and have full control of your previous post, including being able to comment, edit and accept any possible answers, you might want to register one of your accounts and then merge all the existing ones into it by following the procedure described in the help center.

@AJ I don't know, works for me.

Looks like a good movie. I'm a Mike Leigh fan (and Spall and Corden). Thanks for the tip, folks!
